# Vue mutate prop correctly

Tags: vue.js, components, mutation, vue-props

I'm trying to create a simple component whose focus is to display an element in an array, but I'm having issues with Vue's philosophy.

As you may know, if a mutation on a prop is triggered, Vue goes crazy because it doesn't want you to update the value of a prop. You should probably use a store, or emit an event.

The issue is: that since I'm adding functionalities to my codebase (for instance the possibility to start again when I reach the last element of the array), it would be wrong to have an upper component be responsible for this management, as it would be wrong to ask an upper component to change their variable, given that my component is supposed to manage the array, so an emit would be a bad solution.

In the same way, given that I'm making a generic component that can be used multiple times on a page, it would be incorrect to bind it to a store.

EDIT: the reason why the prop needs to be updated is that the component is basically acting as a `<select>`

Am I missing an obvious way to set this up?

To give an example of my end goal, I'm aiming for a component looking like the one in the picture below, and I think a 2 way bind like in `v-model` would be more appropriate than having to set an `@change` just to say to update the value of the passed prop.

[image]

Comment: It's still unclear. Can you please share some code base or structure of the components. So that it will be easy for us to understand the requirement in a more better way.

Comment: Mhh it's kinda hard to without copying the whole component, but basically I'm expanding a `<select>` html component in such a way that I can also change value with some `next element` and `previous element` buttons (and looping if i reach indexes `-1` or `arr.length`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a prop the correct way to update the value is with a sync, as in the following example

Parent:

```html
    <my-component :title.sync="myTitle"></my-component>
```

Child:

```js
    this.$emit("update:title", this.newValue)
```

[Here is](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/vues-v-model-directive-vs-sync-modifier-d1f83957c57c) a very good article talking about the sync method.

By the other hand you can alter a Vuex state variable by calling a Vuex mutation when you change the value:

```js
  computed: {
    title: {
      // getter
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.title
      },
      // setter
      set(newValue) {
         this.setTitle(newValue) // Requires mutation import, see the methods section.
         // Or without import:
         this.$store.commit('setTitle', newValue);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
     ...mapMutations("global", ["setTitle"]) // It is important to import the mutation called in the computed section
  }
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305183/7080573) StackOverflow question they talk about changing state from computed hook in Vue. I hope it works for you.

Comment: It seems not to work for some reason, I'll set up some tests to undestand what's happening in case it's something odd with my codebase and in case accept the answer... regardless, thank you for your contribution!

Comment: I recommend you to read the links I've attached to the answer to check a code with more details.

Comment: I'll accept the answer but weirdly enough sync doesn't work in all vue versions